# Is it possible to pass inline functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inline-functions

When writing code for JavaScript with KotlinJs, we usually have to handle the `this` carefully.

So we usually need this function:

```
inline fun <T> thisAs() = js("this")
```

and use it in somewhere:

```
this.click = {
    thisAs<MyVueComponent.Data>().username = "changed"
}
```

Due to VueJs' inner logic, I have to generate JavaScript code `this.username`(`this` is hardcode), but which is ugly, I don't want to write `thisAs<MyVueComponent.Data>().username` every time I need a JavaScript `this`.

So I tried to improve it by defining a function `defineMethods`, like following:

```
external interface VueComponent<DATA, METHODS> {}

fun <DATA, METHODS> VueComponent<DATA, METHODS>.defineMethods(block: M.(() -> DATA) -> Unit): METHODS {
    val methods = jsObj<M>()
    block(methods, ::thisAs)
    return methods
}
```

And I hope the inline function `thisAs` is still a inline function even if I pass it to the `block` as `::thisAs`, so I can rewrite the code like this:

```
this.methods = this.defineMethods { data ->
    this.click = {
        data().username += "changed!"  // I want to write `data()` to generate a JavaScript `this`
    }
}
```

But sadly, the function `data`(which is `::thisAs`) is not inline anymore, the code is not working properly.

Is there any way to solve this?

---

Update:

- Add a complete project to demo this problem, see: https://github.com/kotlin-demos/kotlin-vue-demo/tree/js-this-issue.

Comment: Are you looking for reified generics? I don't see what exactly you want to solve. Clearly you can't pass around inline functions, that's a contradiction.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for your question. It's a little bit hard to explain, since it need involve some internal logic of Vue. The main problem is I have to hard code `this.username` in generated JavaScript, but I don't want to write `thisAs<MyVueComponent.Data>().username` every time

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I just updated the question, hope this time, it can be clear. Tell me if you have any questions

Comment: You say " the code is not working properly". In what way is it failing?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`. I just add a project link to demo this problem, you can run it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem. I have a similar function for casting Javascript's **this** object as you do. However, I've extended it with a [lambda function with a receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) (the same thing that is used for type-safe builders in Kotlin except that my function returns **Unit** and is inlined).

```
inline fun <T> withJsThis(body: T.() -> Unit) {
  js("this").unsafeCast<T>().body()
}
```

It can be easily used in **methods** as well as in lifecycle hooks (**created**, **mounted**, etc.). It needs one extra line of code but it's clean and produce exactly the expected **this.variable** when translated from Kotlin to Javascript.

```
class LoginComponent {

  class Data {
    var username: String = "test@test.com"
    var password: String = ""
  }

  val data = {
    Data()
  }

  val template = """<form>
      <input type="text" v-model="username" placeholder="Email" /><br />
      <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
      <input type="submit" v-on:click.prevent="showInfo" />
    </form>"""

  val methods = object {

    val showInfo: () -> Unit = {
      withJsThis<Data> {
          console.log("METHOD: USER = $username, PASS = $password")
      }
    }

  }

  fun mounted() {
    withJsThis<Data> {
      console.log("MOUNTED: USER = $username, PASS = $password")
    }
  }

}
```